# Simple PHP Gamification System

Tags: php, sql

I want to code a simple gamification system in PHP.  Things like If count >= 5 then give this person an award.  I assume I would be entering a numbered code into a database once each action is met.  Then I can have an achievements box pull each code out and show the matching badge.

Seems simple enough - but I have an issue.  How would I alert a person ONLY ONCE, upon earning a badge?   Anyone have any ideas for assigning points to each badges worth, and possibly points to other actions?  Would I just enter all the points as individual numbers into an array and add them all up in a sep sql call to display total points?

Comment: You should create a new "notified user" field in your database. This is not a php question.

Comment: Build the first part of your app then worry about the other issues. Often these sorts of problems solve themselves as you code.

Comment: It is a PHP question. The data is stored in a database, and returned via PHP

Comment: Then you'd better start with `DataMappers`

Comment: If you want to alert a person only once, then you'd store somewhere if that person was alerted or not. It might be just a just number in a table, like `1` - was alerted, `0` - wasn't. Then you'd fetch it via `PDO` and handle the rest via basic `if/else` conditions

Comment: This question is about **Data Normalization**

Comment: Dave - Since this is new to me, can you give me a more specific resource to learn more?  Not asking you to explain it all to me, just to refer me to a credible resource on the topic of gamification - or maybe what language is best suited to this project?   (if you reply, please keep in mind the idea is to have a simplistic system nothing grand)

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understood what you mean. I think the simplest way is to implement an "level"-like award system. Simply save the total number of points as a user field (column named "points" in the user table) and check after each increment if the user qualifies for a new award.

If you want to give the user multiple types of awards, not in a specific order, you need to develop a system somewhat based on this structure:

- a table for Awards (all registered awards)
- a table for Awards given to users
- a table for logging the points in which you store an unique id, the user id, points count and the event for which the user gets the points

Then, you simply do a cross-table sql select that shows the points a user or class of users have by simply doing the basic operation:

```
SUM(point awards for the user) - SUM(points for awards received by user).
```

It's been some time since I've written such an SQL select statement, but it is not hard and can totally be done. It would be something similar to this:

```
SELECT a.userId,(SUM(a.points) - SUM(b.points_spent)) as 'currentPoints' FROM Awards a, Spendings b WHERE a.userId = b.userID
```

This statement has not been tested and may be completely wrong but this is as much as I can remember for now. The statement should return every user's id and corresponding spending points. I could provide a complete and correct selection statement provided you supply the database design.

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: Good tip, thank you for your feedback.  How do you suggest going about storing the points.  Should I re-calculate and replace the old point value in a row or store a new row everytime they earn points?

Comment: There are always two sides to a implementation: memory or functionality. If you would like to have a detailed history about user activity that would help you detect fraud you should store each award as a separate entity (row). I would recommend you do it this way. If, on the other hand, you don't need user data and history (yet I am pretty sure you need it now or will need it as you expand your site) you could go with the single field approach. Again, I recommend you go with a distinct table filled with user's awards as specified in my answer. Good luck! :)